# Alternative to nested citations in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I know I'm not supposed to nest citations in `biblatex`. But I do it anyway because it's convenient and mostly works…

In particular, I use it to include something in a citation that should also automatically appear in a list of abbreviations.

However, I've now found that nested citations in related entries *really* don't work :).

So what alternatives are there?

Here's a MWE to play with:

`\autocite{edwards:1999}` works, but `\autocite{victorinus:ephesians}` doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@series{ACCS,
  series = {Ancient Christian Commentary on Scripture},
  shortseries = {ACCS},
  options = {skipbib}
}
@book{edwards:1999,
  editor = {Edwards, Mark J.},
  title = {Galatians, Ephesians, Philippians},
  series = {\citeseries{ACCS} New Testament},
  number = {8},
  location = {Downers Grove, IL},
  publisher = {InterVarsity Press},
  date = {1999}
}
@book{victorinus:ephesians,
  author = {Victorinus, Marius},
  title = {Epistle to the Ephesians},
  related = {edwards:1999}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{edwards:1999}.
Filler text \autocite{victorinus:ephesians}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could disable the test for nested citations, but then you are really on your own. I guess one 'proper' way to solve this would be to introduce another `related`-like field, but I'm not sure if Biber just lets you do that ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be cheating, but it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\notreallyciteseries}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{shortseries}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@series{ACCS,
  series = {Ancient Christian Commentary on Scripture},
  shortseries = {ACCS},
  options = {skipbib}
}
@book{edwards:1999,
  editor = {Edwards, Mark J.},
  title = {Galatians, Ephesians, Philippians},
  series = {\notreallyciteseries{ACCS} New Testament},
  number = {8},
  location = {Downers Grove, IL},
  publisher = {InterVarsity Press},
  date = {1999}
}
@book{victorinus:ephesians,
  author = {Victorinus, Marius},
  title = {Epistle to the Ephesians},
  related = {edwards:1999}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{edwards:1999}.
Filler text \autocite{victorinus:ephesians}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography and citation show "ACCS" correctly.]

The trick here is that `\nocite` does not count as an un-nestable `\cite` command, so we can nest it anywhere we want. `\entrydata` lets us access the relevant entry data as if we were in a cite.

---

A slightly more sophisticated version would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\notreallyciteseries}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\entrydata{#1}{%
       \usebibmacro{shortseries}}}
    {\abx@missing@entry{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

If you need more of those commands, you may as well declare them as follows

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DeclareNotReallyCiteCommand}[2]{%
  \newcommand*{#1}[1]{%
    \nocite{##1}%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}
      {\entrydata{##1}{#2}}
      {\abx@missing@entry{##1}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNotReallyCiteCommand{\notreallyciteseries}{%
  \usebibmacro{shortseries}}
```

As an added bonus those command should not confuse the `biblatex` punctuation tracker in the bibliography in the way nested `\cite` commands might.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what is needed.

Comment: Ah. I spoke too soon. Your solution *only* works in a nested context (`\entrydata` isn't defined if you place `\citeseries` directly into the text). I need them to work in both contexts.

Comment: Is it enough to use `\blx@blxinit` and put everything within a group? e.g., `\newcommand*{\DeclareNestableCiteCommand}[2]{\newcommand*{#1}[1]{\nocite{##1}\blx@ifdata{##1}{\begingroup\blx@blxinit\entrydata{##1}{#2}\endgroup}{\abx@missing@entry{##1}}}}`

Comment: Or perhaps it ought to be `\blx@citeinit` instead of `\blx@blxinit`?

Comment: And even this attempt does not work if `\citeseries` only appears in the bibliography. :(

Comment: I think I'll just ask a new question and give a bunch of examples.

Comment: @DavidPurton A more complicated solution can be found at https://gist.github.com/moewew/b226c78399c89f67417140549c78c940. There we define a real `\cite` command and use it if `\entrydata` is not available. I really like the idea of your `\blx@blxinit` though and at least in a very short test did not manage to break it. I'd be interested in a test case where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Both implementations still fail though when the only for `\begin{document}\nocite{edwards:1999}\printbiblist{abbreviations}\printbibliography\end{document}`. The reason is that `\blx@nocite` does nothing in the bibliography (by design). Changing the definition of `\blx@nocite` then works, but I don't know if this will have unintended side effects.

Comment: Substituting `\blx@xsanitizeafter\blx@nocite@do{##1}` for `\nocite{##1}` seems to work. For now, I will run with this and the `\blx@blxinit` solution. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPurton Ah, I thought I had tested that, but apparently I hadn't. Naively I would have thought that `\nocite` should be fine in the bibliography and that it would be OK to remove the `\iftoggle{blx@bibliography}`, but I have been very wrong about these sort of things before, so I am wary of changing anything here without thinking this through (and preferably having someone else think about it).

Comment: @DavidPurton The `\nocite`-doesn't-work-in-bibliographies issue is tracked at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/901, not sure if anything will come out of it short term (or even longer term).